# Dynamic collapse component not working in bootsrap-vue

Tags: vuejs2, bootstrap-vue

I am trying to add a collapse component from bootstrap-vue into a table I am creating (Not bootstrap-vue table as find it easier to use plain table)

Can anyone tell me why this works as expected (But obviously opens every collapse component with the same ID)

```
<td>
  <fa icon="bars" v-b-toggle.collapse2/>  
</td>
</tr>
 <td colspan="4">
  <b-collapse id="collapse2" >
    <b-card>
      <p class="card-text">Collapse contents Here</p>
    </b-card>
  </b-collapse>
 </td>
```

But this doesn't work, I know i have a unique id in case.id

```
<td>
  <fa icon="bars" v-b-toggle="'collapse-' + case.id" />  
</td>
</tr>
 <td colspan="4">
  <b-collapse id="'collapse-' + case.id" >
    <b-card>
      <p class="card-text">Collapse contents Here</p>
    </b-card>
  </b-collapse>
 </td>
```

Many Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You are not setting up a proper attribute binding in `id="'collapse-' + case.id"`. It works in `v-b-toggle="'collapse-' + case.id"` case because as stated in the [docs](https://v1.vuejs.org/guide/syntax.html#Directives)

> Directive attribute values are expected to be **binding expressions**

In case of attributes you should use one of the following:

[mustache](https://v1.vuejs.org/guide/syntax.html#Attributes)

```
<div id="item-{{ id }}"></div>
```

[v-bind](https://v1.vuejs.org/guide/syntax.html#Arguments)

```
<div v-bind:id="'item-' + id"></div>
```

[shorthand :](https://v1.vuejs.org/guide/syntax.html#v-bind-Shorthand)

```
<div :id="'item-' + id"></div>
```